# My code is not working as I imagined it to... (beginner coder here)

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code isnt outputting the expected output

The code consists of a module file (degree.py) and 6 other files that run the module and output a temperature in (C, F or K) from user input in (C, F, K)
in other words, the 6 files converts between the different degrees respectively
Heres the module file (degree.py):

```
#degrees (Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin)

bruh = float(0)
c_1 = float((5/9) * (float(bruh) - 32)) #F to C
c_2 = float((float(bruh) - 273.15) * 1) #K to C
f_1 = float(((9/5) * float(bruh)) + 32) #C to F
f_2 = float((float(bruh)-273.15) * (9/5) + 32) #K to F
k_1 = float((float(bruh) + 273.15) * 1) #C to K
k_2 = float((float(bruh)-32) * (5/9) + 273.15) #F to K
```

And heres one of the 6 files (fahrenheitToCelsius.py):

```
import degree

test = False 
while test == False:
    bruh = input("Enter a positive numerical value: ")
    bruh.isnumeric() 
    if bruh.isnumeric() == True:
        print("If the temperature is", bruh, "degrees in Fahrenheit, then it is", degree.c_1, "degrees in Celsius.")
        print()
        print("Do acknowledge that the calculations done here in Python alone are not going to be precise.")
        test = True
    else:
        print("This was not a numerical value bruh :(")
        test = False
```

As the name suggests, this specific code was supposed to convert a value from degree F to C.

However I am noticing that the outputs are incorrect, first I thought it was a float margin error, but I soon to find out the culprit could be from the value `bruh` somehow becoming `0`

I would really like to be enlightened into why the code isn't working. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me solve this problem.

Comment: In your own words: if I want to make a peanut butter sandwich, and I know how to do two things: spread peanut butter on bread, and take bread out of a bag, which should I do first? So, the same thing here. If I want to, say, calculate the celcius equivalent of some fahrenheit number, which should I do first: apply the conversion formula to the number, or decide what the number is? You should make sure you understand these kinds of fundamentals about writing a program, **before** trying to work with modules.

Comment: You should consider a radical redesign of degree.py Perhaps develop a class with methods for converting the various temperature scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you assign **bruh = float(0)** in degrees.py

```
#degrees (Celsius, Fahrenheit, Kelvin)
bruh = float(0)
c_1 = float((5/9) * (float(bruh) - 32)) #F to C
```

in degrees.py, bruh is always 0 and does not take the input value.

you should **def a function** in degree.py, like:

```
def f_2_c(bruh):
    c_1 = float((5/9) * (float(bruh) - 32)) 
    return c1
```

and use in  ahrenheitToCelsius.py

```
if bruh.isnumeric() == True:
    c_1 = degree.f_2_c(bruh)
    print("If the temperature is", bruh, "degrees in Fahrenheit, then it is", c_1 , "degrees in Celsius.")
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the help, I have one question:
If I already defined c_1 as ```float((5/9) * (float(bruh) - 32))```
in f_2_c(bruh) in degree.py, why do I have to type ```c_1= degree.f_2_c(bruh)``` in the other file?

Comment: " If I already defined c_1 as float((5/9) * (float(bruh) - 32)) in f_2_c(bruh) in degree.py" - first off, because that means, "take the value that `bruh` has **in this file, right now**, compute a result, and let `c_1` be a name for **the result**". Second, because that sets the value of `c_1` **for that module**; every module gets its own set of variables, and if you want to use them from another module then you have to reach in to get them explicitly.

Comment: When you define a function, the statements within the function are not executed.
It is only executed when the function is called( c_1= degree.f_2_c(bruh) )

Documentation about functions：
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions